# Dynamically change borderContainer size in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, resize, dijit.layout

I have the following borderContainer whose size is hardcoded. I'm trying to change it dynamically based on the screen resolution :

```
<div id="border1" dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" 
     style="width: 1010px; height: 500px">
    ...
</div>
```

I tried to do the following to change it dynamically and it does not seem to work

```
dojo.require("dojo/window");
var bc = dijit.byId("borderContainer");   
dojo.setStyle(bc.domNode, "height", screen.height+"px");
dojo.setStyle(bc.domNode, "width", screen.width+"px");
```

Comment: why not setting at start widht and , height  to 100% ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

Get the `BorderContainer`:

```
    var bc = dijit.byId("borderContainer");
```

and then set the style `set` for its `style` property:

```
    bc.set('style',"height: 300px; width: 500px;");
```

Comment: It's always a good idea, when answering, to offer a bit of explanation as to what your answer is doing to answer the original question, as opposed to just pasting a snip of code.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is I suggest to you to switch to modern dojo architecture
[AMD](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/) DOJO wich load asynchronously you modules :

Now , you can set only css style at first by setting `width` and `height` to `100`% , and **Important**  thing here is to set it's parent to 100% hieght and width ( also for body )

Otherwise you can use programmatic approach :
first set `body` height and width to `100`% 
when window resized set border container node to 100%.

```js
require([ "dojo/on","dojo/dom-style", "dojo/ready", "dijit/registry", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane"],function(On, domStyle,ready,registry,BorderContainer,ContentPane){
 ready(function(){
    var borderContainer = registry.byId("bc");
    bcDomNode = borderContainer.domNode;
    
    On(window,"resize",function(e){
      domStyle.set(bcDomNode,'width','100%');
      domStyle.set(bcDomNode,'height','100%');
     
    })
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      domStyle.set(bcDomNode,'width','100%');
      domStyle.set(bcDomNode,'height','100%');
    },3000)
    
  })
  
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script>
    dojoConfig= {
        parseOnLoad: true,
        async: true
    };
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="bc" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" style="width: 1010px; height: 500px">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" id="center">center</div>
  </div>
</body>
```